# Access to Excel VBA SQL Join

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have two tables in a database in access and I want to perform CRUD operations from excel vba. Though I was able to perform CRUD into individual tables separately, but it says some JOIN Error while performing CRUD on both the tables at same time.Here are the
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VplxH.jpg) &
[Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRxUB.jpg) between them.
I tried something like this but it says a JOIN Error

```
"Select CustomerT.First_Name,ProductT.Product_Name,CutomerT.Age From CustomerT Inner Join ProductT ON Customer.ID = ProductT.Customer_ID"
```

My main aim is to find out the details about the customer ans the product he/she ordered by entering the customer id. 
Please suggest what to do.

Here is the full code that I am using

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Access2Excel\DB1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
'Open Db connection
con.Open
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open "Select CustomerT.First_Name,ProductT.Product_Name,CutomerT.Age From CustomerT Inner Join ProductT ON CustomerT.ID = ProductT.Customer_ID "             
StartRow = 3
Do Until rs.EOF

'first field
Cells(StartRow, 4) = rs.Fields(0).Value
'second field
Cells(StartRow, 5) = rs.Fields(1).Value
'Third field
Cells(StartRow, 6) = rs.Fields(2).Value


rs.MoveNext
StartRow = StartRow + 1
Loop
Set rs = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a `T` missing in `Customer.ID`. The join should be like:

```
Select CustomerT.First_Name,ProductT.Product_Name,CustomerT.Age 
From CustomerT Inner Join ProductT ON CustomerT.ID = ProductT.Customer_ID
```

**Edit:**

Also changed `CutomerT.Age`to `CustomerT.Age`, thanks LondonRob!

Comment: Yes Thanks for pointing that out. After adding that "T" it says

Run-time error - 2147217904(8004010)
No value given for one or more required parameters

Interestingly the same code works fine with simple SQL queries

Comment: Messages about required parameters are always due to a typo in one of the column names. If you type, say, `firstname` instead of `first_name`, the Access engine interprets the name as a parameter to the query, and expects a value for the parents to be provided.

Comment: Have a look at `CutomerT.Age`. You're missing an S.

Comment: Thanks @LondonRob can't believe that had so many typos in that.
I was more concerned about the validity of the SQL statement rather than checking the typos :(